# Insert Image automatically when upload finishes wordpress media uploader

Tags: wordpress

What I am trying to do is -

1) User clicks "Add Media"

2) Select an image

3) Image uploads finishes

4) Now it should insert into post automatically without pressing "Insert into post".

Anyway to hook inside word-press, and click the "Insert into post" using jquery.

Any clues ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yeh, Posting the answer.

Comment: Have a look on this one - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167358/62887

Comment: hope it helps, cheers :)

Comment: That's not working for me in WP 4.2.x. Too bad.